# Facebook tutorial application for android doesnt work

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm trying to create [following](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/android_sso/) autorization application for android.

But after pressing "login" button I see progressDialog "signing in" and then alertDialog "An error occured during sign in. Please try again later".

In my LogCat i can see:

```
INFO/ActivityManager(88): Displayed activity com.facebook.katana/.LoginActivity: 1505 ms (total 5499 ms)
DEBUG/dalvikvm(222): GC_EXPLICIT freed 704 objects / 39192 bytes in 163ms 
ERROR/HttpOperation.run(1226): class org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException Connect to /69.171.224.20:443 timed out [https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?api_key=882a8490361da98702bf97a021ddc14d&email=artem.chilin%40gmail.com&format=JSON&method=auth.login&migrations_override=%7B%27empty_json%27%3A+true%7D&password=******&sig=a59e0d73af109b2f70e7682b17206cf1&v=1.0]
ERROR/HttpOperation(1226): Encountered exception: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /69.171.224.20:443 timed out 
WARN/System.err(1226): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /69.171.224.20:443 timed out 
WARN/System.err(1226):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) 
WARN/System.err(1226):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143) 
WARN/System.err(1226):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164) 
WARN/System.err(1226):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119) 
WARN/System.err(1226):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348) 
WARN/System.err(1226):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555) 
WARN/System.err(1226):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487) 
WARN/System.err(1226):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465) 
WARN/System.err(1226):     at com.facebook.katana.service.method.HttpOperation.run(HttpOperation.java:163) 
WARN/InputManagerService(88): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4507c230
```

Note: I have a proxy. I've set it in settengs/wireless and networks/mobile networks/apns and I can access facebook with default android browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FacebookConnector.java class, change com.facebook.katana to com.facebook.katana2. Changing proxy server names worked for me

Comment: Behavior has changed but not acceptable at all. Now I see infinite "loading" progressDialog so I cant to input my login/password. And application apperance has changed! See difference on screenshots: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/94/katanay.png/ and http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/845/katana2.png/. How 1 digit made application change it's appearance?

Answer (score 1):

LogCat tells you, that you have a ConnectionTimeoutError. I guess your proxy is too slow